# Android ScrollView not Scrolling

Tags: android, android-activity, android-scrollview

I have this layout for a activity  but it does not scroll. How can I find out the solution?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.gurkhatech.schoolmanagementteachers.classrooms.singleclass.students.studentsdetails.StudentDetailsActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_student_details">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_student_in_content_student_details"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"


                        />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/student_name_in_student_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"


                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/student_class_in_content_student_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/birthday_in_content_student_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""


                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sex_in_content_student_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""

                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">


            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="10dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/blood_group_students_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Blood Group"
                        android:textSize="16sp"

                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/address_students_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""

                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/email_in_content_students_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/phone_in_content_students_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_upload_student_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="@string/upload_image"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/primary" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: where is scroll-view??

Comment: Add Scroll View as a root

Comment: Scrollview missing

Comment: sorry guys the the codehighlight was mistakenly applied after relative layout

Comment: add `android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: @LaxmanBhattarai I tried your code and its perfectly scrolling. May be your screen is larger and it not required scrolling. Try to add same views to it so it will occupy more space and you able to scroll

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot yes yes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `fillViewport` in your **ScrollView** Section .

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true"
```

**[android:fillViewport](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport)**

> Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the
>   viewport.

**FYI**

Avoid to set large Hard-coded VALUE .`android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"`

Answer (score 0):

**Your Updated Code at your point of view -- its working**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_student_in_content_student_details"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/student_name_in_student_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/ans_post_time_color"


                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/student_class_in_content_student_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/ans_post_time_color"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/birthday_in_content_student_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="sdf asdf asdf asdf asdf "
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sex_in_content_student_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""

                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">


            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="10dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/blood_group_students_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Blood Group"
                        android:textSize="16sp"

                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/address_students_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""

                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/email_in_content_students_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/phone_in_content_students_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_upload_student_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Upload Image"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you need to use Scrollview after Relative its working.