# View Pager not scrolling in a scrollView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I'm having a `ViewPager` and a `RecyclerView` in layout file. I want to make the entire layout Scrollable. That is i want the ViewPager to be scrolled up. Hence, i added `<ScrollView>` as the root layout.

**Issue:**

The problem i'm facing is that the `RecyclerView` in scrolling as expected, but the `ViewPager` area is fixed.

The Below Image depicts the issue mentioned above:

[image]

The xml code of my layout file is as shown below:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/home_viewpager_guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/home_viewpager_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_viewpager_dots_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/home_viewpager_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"></LinearLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/latest_news_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/latest_news_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_view_pager">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.16"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/latest_news_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Latest News"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/latest_news_guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.51" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_article_type_txt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="Featured Article"
            android:textColor="@color/pf_white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/home_viewpager_dots_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_article_title_txt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="What better way to put your health and wellbeing first than"
            android:textColor="@color/pf_white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/home_viewpager_dots_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_article_type_txt"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/home_article_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**What have i tried?**
As mentioned in this answer [Android ScrollView not Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404706/android-scrollview-not-scrolling)
, i have tried setting the `ScrollView` orientation to vertical and `fillViewPort` property to true, but the problem still persists.

I have also tried using `NestedScrollView` as the root, but that too didn't work.

If someone can suggest me how to go about with this, it will be really helpful to anyone facing such issue.

Comment: Try the nestedscrollingEnabled flag on both view pager and nestedScrollView

Comment: Have you tried _.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)_?

Comment: @SarthakGandhi: This flag is for ScrollView or NestedScrollView?

Comment: NestedScrollView and use it on the viewpager as well. Like you can try the combination of using it on both or individually but it sure resolves the problem.

Comment: @SarthakGandhi Getting this  'Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView' in the fragment where i inflate the above layout

Comment: It is just the preview don't worry about it. And set the flag in the java or kotlin file

Comment: And you can have only one child layout inside nestingScrollingView, that might be the case.

Comment: @SarthakGandhi The flag must be set to false or true?

Comment: It has to be false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191005/discussion-between-sarthak-gandhi-and-zax).